# Rewriting two-body operator in second-quantized form

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, second-quantization, density-functional-theory

I would like to understand the following identity for fermion field operators:

$$\psi^\dagger(x) \psi^\dagger(y) \psi(y) \psi(x) = \psi^\dagger(x) \psi(x) \psi^\dagger(y) \psi(y) - \delta(x - y) \psi^\dagger(x) \psi(x).$$

I understand one arrives at this equation from the anticommutation relations of fermion field operators:

$$\{\psi^\dagger(x),\psi^\dagger(y)\} = \{\psi(x),\psi(y)\} = 0$$
$$\{\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y)\} = \delta (x-y)$$

However I do not understand why the last field operators are mapped on x, instead of both x and y

I would really appreciate if anyone could answer this question.

[image: identity for the two-body operator] .

Comment: Welcome Sergio, note that if the attached image is an essential part of your question you should transcribe it. [See more information here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563)

Comment: Because there's a $\delta(x-y)$ multiplying them, and of course, $\delta(x-y)f(x)=\delta(x-y)f(y)$.